# Finding a module in javascript

Tags: javascript, import

My file structure is:

```
src
  components
    home.js
  main.js
```

I'm exporting a variable from 'main.js' and want to import it in 'home.js'.
In the 'home.js' I'm trying to get the exported variable by calling "import ref from '../main' " and I'm getting an error saying it cannot find the module.

I'm exporting the variable using "export const ref = ...."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will need a bit more info to answer this: How are you exporting the variable (default export)? Does your build system handle extensions automatically (maybe '../main.js' will work)?

Comment: It's most likely a timing issue. Try to export the variable befor you import the file that needs it. Also **try** to use require and see if it fixes it, both behave slightly different in my experience.

Comment: Also, you should use import {ref}, since ref is not your default export.